# How to get position of a sprite having action CCRotate?

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ccrotateby

I have a node and I've fixed the position of that node. Then I added a sprite as a child of that node (which I've added earlier). After that I try to rotate the node by some angle.

As a result sprite is also rotating and its center point is position of node. Now my question is, how can I get the position of sprite?

Answer (score 0):

Sprite position is the same - "Center of node".

I don't understand what exact position do you want to evaluate. And I hope follow methods will help you:

Each CCNode (and all sublcasses CCSprite, CCLayer etc) have follow helpers that very useful for evaluation coords between nodes:

```
- (CGPoint)convertToNodeSpace:(CGPoint)worldPoint;
- (CGPoint)convertToWorldSpace:(CGPoint)nodePoint;
- (CGPoint)convertToNodeSpaceAR:(CGPoint)worldPoint;
- (CGPoint)convertToWorldSpaceAR:(CGPoint)nodePoint;
```

Comment: i want to rotate a bat with respect to an anchor point. But when im rotating the anchor point im not getting the position of bat which is also rotating and we can see that position of bat is changing . but Im not getting the bat position..!!! should i place my code here ???

Comment: i got the position of bat using formulae of transformation.!! :-)